# wp_mail is returns false when customizing WordPress theme locally

Tags: wordpress, smtp, wordpress-theming, wp-mail

I am customizing a new theme for my wordpress locally. I have form for sending an email.but its not working. When i am trying with below code in my functions.php, i am getting 'email error!' instead of 'email sent successfully'

```
add_action('wp_ajax_enquiry','form_enquiry');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_enquiry','form_enquiry');
function form_enquiry(){

$formdata=[];
wp_parse_str($_POST['enquiry'],$formdata);

$admin_email='devleena@spark.io';

$headers[]='Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$headers[]='From: My Website <'.$admin_email.'>';
$headers[]='Reply-to:'  .$formdata['email'];

$send_to=$admin_email;

$subject='Enquiry from '.$formdata['fname'].' '.$formdata['lname'];

$message='';
foreach($formdata as $index=>$field){
    $message .= '<strong>'.$index.'</strong>:'.$field.'</br>';

}
try{
    if(wp_mail($send_to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        wp_send_json_success('email sent successfully!');
    }else{
        wp_send_json_error('email error!');
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    wp_send_json_error($e->getMessage());
}
}
```

Here the arguments passing to wp_mail() are valid one.But still it returns false. As i am new to this i didn't understand why it returns false instead of true. My form.php code is given below

```
<form id="enquiry">
-----
</form>
<script>
 (function($){
    $('#enquiry').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var endpoint= '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>'
        var form= $('#enquiry').serialize();
        var formdata = new FormData;
        formdata.append('action','enquiry');
        formdata.append('enquiry',form);

        $.ajax(endpoint,{
            type:'POST',
            data:formdata,
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            success: function(res){
                alert(res.data);
            },
            error:function(err){
                alert(err.responseJSON.data);
            }
        })
    })
 })(jQuery)    
</script>
```

Am i going wrong?.Can anyone please help?